# Evitar submit do form ao pressionar a tecla Enter

Tags: javascript, html, formulário, vue.js, formulário-submeter

Tenho um `input` no VueJS que está dentro de um `form` e quando eu pressionar `enter` não quero que o `form` seja submetido.

Junto com o VueJS estou usando o Quasar e consegui atribuir a chamada da função somente na tecla `enter`:

```
<form @keydown.enter="evitarSubmit">
```

Função:

```
evitarSubmit () {
  console.log('Tentou evitar')
}
```

Estou com dificuldade para encontrar e elaborar um código que anule o efeito do `enter` sobre o `form`, mas aceito sugestões...

Comment: se você esta conseguindo entrar certinho no `evitarSubmit()`, é só colocar um `event.preventDefault()`, que ele cancela o form submit.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895171/prevent-users-from-submitting-a-form-by-hitting-enter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tens várias maneiras. Uma delas é usar `@keydown.enter.prevent` na `<form>`. Isso previne o submit mas também previne o `enter` de ser usado onde foi pressionado, e talvez esse efeito seja indesejado.

Outra maneira é usar `@keydown.enter.stop` localmente no input em questão, ou criando uma `div` à volta desses inputs e colocar lá para impedir o evento de propagar até ao `form`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      input1: '',
      input2: '',
      textarea: ''
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <form action="/foo">
    <div @keydown.enter.stop>
      <input type="text" v-model="input1" />
      <input type="text" v-model="input2" />
      <textarea v-model="textarea"></textarea>
    </div>
  </form>
  <p>{{input1}}</p>
  <p>{{input2}}</p>
  <p>{{textarea}}</p>
</div>
```

### Obs:

Há um detalhe a ter em conta. Os browsers comportam-se de maneira diferente quando só têm 1 input. Aí o método de cima não funciona e tens de usar algo assim:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      input: '',
      textarea: ''
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <form action="/foo">
      <input type="text" v-model="input" @keydown.enter.stop.prevent/>
      <textarea v-model="textarea"></textarea>
  </form>
  <p>{{input}}</p>
  <p>{{textarea}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Capture o enter no seu formulário e previna com que o evento de `submit` dispare assim:

```
event.returnValue=false;
event.cancel = true;
```

Segue exemplo funcionando:

```js
function EnterKeyFilter()
{  
  if (window.event.keyCode == 13)
  {   
      event.returnValue=false;
      event.cancel = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<form onkeydown="EnterKeyFilter();">
  <input type="text" name="teste" placeholder="pressione enter"/>
  <button type="submit" name="btnTeste">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: mas até um botão submit não funcionará

Comment: Corrigi o código, veja agora

Comment: agora está correto, meu + 1 dado